# A condition that all convex combination of two elements in a uni sphere of Banach space belongs to unit sphere

Tags: convex-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $S_X=\{x\in X:\Vert x\Vert=1\}$. 
If $x, y, \frac{x+y}{2}\in S_X$, is it true that $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in S_X$ for every $\lambda \in [0,1]$? I can show this if $X$ is a Hilbert space, but in general there is no inner product and no parallel law. Can you give a hint?

Comment: Did you mean the ball $\{ ‖ x ‖ \le 1 \}$?

Comment: @Calvin No. It is a sphere.

Comment: I'm also having a hard time understanding how the average of $x$ and $y$ can be on the sphere, if the Euclidean norm is used? Any convex combination lies on a line between the points, no? Sorry if it is obvious.

Comment: This is a general Banach space. For Euclidean norm, I think it is hard to find such points.

Comment: For Hilbert spaces does it not follow that $\|x-y\|^2 = 2\|x\|^2 + 2 ‖y‖^2 - 4 ‖ (x+y)/2 ‖^2 = 0$?

Comment: Yes I prove it by something like that. Is it true in Banach space?

Comment: It's a little odd that the question has no content in Hilbert spaces. I don't know if it's true in a Banach space? I'll come back if I think of something...

Comment: it's true - if $\Vert \lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\Vert<1$ for some $\lambda\in(0,1/2)$, express $(x+y)/2$ as a convex combination of $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$ and of $y$ to get $\Vert (x+y)/2\Vert<1$. Similarly for $\lambda\in(1/2,1)$.

Comment: Oh. In fact this is true for any normed space! amazing!

Comment: For anyone else who was wondering if the assumptions can be satisfied without $x=y$: take $x= \Bbb 1_{[0,2]} $ and $y=\Bbb 1_{[1,3]}$ with the sup norm on $\Bbb R$. The $L^p$ spaces for $1\le p<infty$ satisfy a weak parallelogram law which is also enough to imply $x=y$ as in the case of Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 3):

May assume $$\lambda\in \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right).$$ If $$\Vert \lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\Vert<1,$$ then since $$\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y=\frac{1}{2\lambda}[\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y]+\left(1-\frac{1}{2\lambda}\right)y,$$ $$\Vert\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y\Vert<\frac{1}{2\lambda}\cdot 1+\left(1-\frac{1}{2\lambda}\right)\cdot 1=1,$$ a contradiction.

Comment: seems for $\lambda\in(0,1/2)$ you should use $x$ instead of $y$ in your convex combination (notice that $1/(2\lambda)>1$ -you don't want to use that number)

Comment: I changed the range of $\lambda$ thanks.